# How to initialize a ByteBuffer if you don't know how many bytes to allocate beforehand?

Tags: java, initialization, bytebuffer

Is this:

```
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(1000);
```

...the only way to initialize a `ByteBuffer`?

What if I have no idea how many bytes I need to allocate..?

**Edit:** More details:

I'm converting one image file format to a TIFF file. The problem is the starting file format can be any size, but I need to write the data in the TIFF to little endian. So I'm reading the stuff I'm eventually going to print to the TIFF file into the ByteBuffer first so I can put everything in Little Endian, then I'm going to write it to the outfile. I guess since I know how long IFDs are, headers are, and I can probably figure out how many bytes in each image plane, I can just use multiple ByteBuffers during this whole process.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depends.

## Library

Converting file formats tends to be a solved problem for most problem domains. For example:

- [Batik](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/using/transcoder.html) can transcode between various image formats (including TIFF).
- [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) can convert between office spreadsheet formats.
- [Flexmark](https://github.com/vsch/flexmark-java) can generate HTML from Markdown.

The list is long. The first question should be, "What [library](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) can accomplish this task?" If performance is a consideration, your time is likely better spent optimising an existing package to meet your needs than writing yet another tool. (As a bonus, other people get to benefit from the centralised work.)

---

## Known Quantities

- Reading a file? Allocate `file.size()` bytes.
- Copying a string? Allocate `string.length()` bytes.
- Copying a TCP packet? Allocate 1500 bytes, for example.

## Unknown Quantities

When the number of bytes is truly unknown, you can do a few things:

- Make a guess.
- Analyze example data sets to buffer; use the average length.

## Example

Java's `StringBuffer`, unless otherwise instructed, uses an initial buffer size to hold 16 characters. Once the 16 characters are filled, a new, longer array is allocated, and then the original 16 characters copied. If the `StringBuffer` had an initial size of 1024 characters, then the reallocation would not happen as early or as often.

## Optimization

Either way, this is probably a premature optimization. Typically you would allocate a set number of bytes when you want to reduce the number of internal memory reallocations that get executed.

It is unlikely that this will be the application's bottleneck.

Comment: A `StringBuffer` behaves differently. A `ByteBuffer` would just throw a `BufferOverflowException` if you try to add more.

Answer (score 17):

The types of places that you would use a `ByteBuffer` are generally the types of places that you would otherwise use a byte array (which also has a fixed size). With synchronous I/O you often use byte arrays, with asynchronous I/O, ByteBuffers are used instead.

If you need to read an unknown amount of data using a `ByteBuffer`, consider using a **loop** with your buffer and append the data to a [ByteArrayOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) as you read it. When you are finished, call `toByteArray()` to get the final byte array.

Any time when you aren't absolutely sure of the size (or maximum size) of a given input, reading in a loop (possibly using a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, but otherwise just processing the data as a stream, as it is read) is the only way to handle it. Without some sort of loop, any remaining data will of course be lost.

For example:

```
final byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
int numRead;

// Use try-with-resources to auto-close streams.
try(
  final FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(...);
  final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
) {
  while ((numRead = fis.read(buf)) > 0) {
    baos.write(buf, 0, numRead);
  }

  final byte[] allBytes = baos.toByteArray();

  // Do something with the data.
}
catch( final Exception e ) {
  // Do something on failure...
}
```

If you instead wanted to write Java `int`s, or other things that aren't raw bytes, you can wrap your `ByteArrayOutputStream` in a [`DataOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html):

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(baos);

while (thereAreMoreIntsFromSomewhere()) {
    int someInt = getIntFromSomewhere();
    dos.writeInt(someInt);
}

byte[] allBytes = baos.toByteArray();
```

Comment: Can you give an example of this using the ByteArrayOutputStream? Like let's say for an integer?

Comment: @PaulaKristin Check it out now (I've also fixed the broken `ByteArrayOutputStream` link)

Answer (score 7):

The idea is that it's only a *buffer* - not the whole of the data. It's a temporary resting spot for data as you read a chunk, process it (possibly writing it somewhere else). So, allocate yourself a big enough "chunk" and it normally won't be a problem.

What problem are you anticipating?