# how to write a fixed number of bytes from a bytebuffer into the file in java

Tags: java, file-io, bytebuffer

I allocate a big bytebuffer and read in some information (not use all the space associated with this buffer).

Then I want to exactly input the used bytes into a file after filp();

what should I do.

```
ByteBuffer buffer = new ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
buffer.getInt(1);
buffer.getInt(2);
buffer.flip();
```

for example, after above code, I just write `fc.write(buffer)`?

How I tell the computer that I only need 8 bytes to input to the fc?

thanks!

Comment: i would suggest a java nio tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

See the [FileChannel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#write%28java.nio.ByteBuffer%29)

You need not tell the computer regarding the number of bytes to be written, the filechannel will take care of it itself.

It will write from 0 to limit() bytes.

Do this after you flip the buffer, you should be fine.

Comment: hi, if I find allocate space is too small, could I reallocate it?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396016/how-to-initialize-a-bytebuffer-if-you-dont-know-how-many-bytes-to-allocate-befo